# Linker error:1112 module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'IA64'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, com, atl

Iam getting the following linker error while building an atl com dll which is targeted to IA64 using a makefile on an XP platform..

```
1>atls.lib(atlcommodule.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'IA64'
1>NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\x86_IA64\link.exe"' : return code '0x458'

Can anyone tell where I made a mistake?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say where in this particular case the error is coming from, but usually it means that you are trying to link to libs compiled for a different target architecture than your code is.

You say you want to generate IA64 code, but something is compiled for x86 (probably the libs)

Comment: I have posted the compiler options in the main post, where /D "WIN64" is provided..

Answer (score 0):

The very first line talks about atlcommodule.obj from atls.lib. How was that compiled? Is it perhaps included from an x86 directory?

Comment: I dnt know how  atlcommodule.obj from atls.lib is being compiled here

Answer (score 0):

That is link target platform mismatch. Not the compiler problem.

Check you project file for the following code. If you find it, remove it.

```
 <Link>
  ...
  <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
</Link>
```